# Need to setup git repository locally without github

Tags: git

i want to setup repository in server using git not in Github. While creating branch it throws fatal error "this operation must be run in a work tree". Please guide me how to setup branch and further steps for creating git repository locally rather in github

Comment: *"Need to setup git repository locally"* -- use [`git init`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init). Read the [Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) (or relevant fragments of it) for a quick start on Git usage.

Comment: @axiac I think the OP might be asking how to host its own Git repo locally...somewhere.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen on the second reading of the question I think you're probably right.

Comment: It seems you have already created a bare Git repo. Read chapter 4, [Git on the Server](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols). There are several ways to access your bare repo from another computer.

Comment: @axiac is right. You should check if you have created bare repository. You can run this command inside your repo `git rev-parse --is-bare-repository`

Answer (score -1):

- Create a directory to contain the project.
- Go into the new directory.
- Type git init.
- Write some code.
- Type git add to add the files.
- Type git commit.

if you want you can read more details from [here](http://kbroman.org/github_tutorial/pages/init.html) and do all the stuff from their until "Connect it to github"

Good luck.

its simple :-)

Comment: i have done upto what you told.But i need to create a branch."Git checkout -b master" this command throws me error.